# Add new parameter to promise all chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use the following code which is working as expected, Now I need to add the

```
modifyOpt()
```

function,currently this is working and in the return I pass args[2]
which is working, now I need add additional thing...
I need  to send the return (which is port) from`portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync`  also to `modifyOpt()`, to be like `modifyOpt(port)`
How should I do that ?

```
return Promise.all([
    fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8').then(pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user')), 
    portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(3000, 4000, 'localhost'),
    modifyOpt()

]).then(function(args) {
    return processExe('exec', args[0], args[1],args[2]);
})
```

Comment: Do you mean `portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(…).then(modifyOpt)`?

Comment: @Bergi - i Need to pass the 3 args to the processExe as before and in addition from portScanner move the port to modifyOpt() function,is it more clear now ?

Comment: So you want to call `modifyOpt` twice? Or do you want to call it once but use its result twice?

Comment: @Bergi - the second option,read once and you result twice.Thanks!

Comment: Is `modifyOpt` asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain the `modifyOpt` after the `portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(…)`  promise with `then` to get the fulfillment value as a parameter.
If you need to use its result twice, just pass the result two times to `processExec`.

```
return Promise.all([
    fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8').then(pars.getEx.bind(null, 'user')), 
    portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(3000, 4000, 'localhost').then(modifyOpt)
]).then(function(args) {
    return processExe('exec', args[0], args[1], args[1]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Now I got the value of the port in modifyOpt function but the options(which is response from modifyOpt) are not passed to args[2],any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: Ignore the last comment , my mistake , this is working,thanks a lot!

Comment: HI Again, the problem is that now I dont get the port to the  processExe...I got the options and the command but not the port,any idea what can be wrong ? the modifyOpt is getting the port....

Comment: Currently the port is returned from the findPort,can I add additional function to  then(modifyOpt) to be Like then(modifyOpt , updatePortFunc) ,the order is not so impotent ...Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just write `modifyOpt` so that it returns you all the data you need for calling `processExe`? You're quite free in choosing an appropriate data structure here.